# Нету доступа к переменной(Notice: undefined index)

Tags: php

В файле functions.php есть функция:

```
function findPopularDirection() {
    global $geo;
    $currency = getCurrencyCode($geo['country_name']);
    $origin = $geo['iata'];
    $url = "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/city-directions?origin=" . $origin . "&currency=" . $currency;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: - ")); //токен доступа к API скрыл в целях безопасности
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $popular = json_decode($response, true);
    return $popular;
}
```

Есть индексный файл, к которому подключен файл `functions.php` и вызвана сама функция:

```
require('php/functions.php');
$popular = findPopularDirection();
```

Переменная $popular содержит в себе многомерный массив, который я пытаюсь вывести через `foreach()`:

```
foreach($popular as $item) {
   echo $item['origin'];
   echo $item['destination'];
}
```

Но получаю ошибку **Notice: undefined index**. Что я делаю неправильно? Подозреваю, что у меня неправильно организована сама запись массива в переменную.

Comment: Так выведите `$popular` и посмотрите как оно устроено.

Comment: var_dump($popular) - и правда, посмотрите на ключи и значения. зачем гадать?

Answer (score 2):

Эх, ленивый нынче программист пошёл, не любит напрягаться и читать [документацию](https://support.travelpayouts.com/hc/ru/articles/203956163#20) :) А ведь там пример успешного ответа для этой точки входа в API расписан подробно:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "data":{
    "AER":{
      "origin":"MOW",
      "destination":"AER",
      "price":3673,
      "transfers":0,
      "airline":"WZ",
      "flight_number":125,
      "departure_at":"2016-03-08T16:35:00Z",
      "return_at":"2016-03-17T16:05:00Z",
      "expires_at":"2016-02-22T09:32:44Z"
    }
  },
  "error":null,
  "currency":"rub"
}
```

Стало быть:

```
$popular = json_decode( $data, true );
if( $popular['success'] ) {
    foreach($popular['data'] as $type => $item) {
        printf( "%-16s : %s\n", 'Type', $type );
        foreach( $item as $key => $val ) {
            printf( "%-16s : %s\n", $key, $val );
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
} 
else {
    /* что будет если success не true - в документацию! */
}
```

Comment: Правильно. Запрос возвращает мне json-строку, которую я уже декодирую в многомерный массив. Вы обратили внимание на документацию, но документация (фигня полнейшая) не говорит о том, что такой запрос выводит не один массив, а 10. И вместо AER там каждый раз разные ключи.

Comment: И что вам мешает перебирать эти разные ключи? В любом случае вы даже близко не туда смотрите в вашем коде, надо-то из `'data'` вынимать, а не из массива верхнего уровня.

Comment: Хорошо. И как мне перебирать эти ключи?

Comment: *И как мне перебирать эти ключи?* - да как обычно, в любом учебнике по PHP написано... См. обновление ответа.

Comment: Окей, я получил форматированный список `ключ:значение`. Как теперь его парсить?

Comment: Нужные вам пары `ключ:значение` лежат в элементах массивов `$item`, которые, в свою очередь являются значениями массива `$popular['data']`. Что и как с ними делать - решать вам.

Comment: Забавно, но почему-то у меня запустился бесконечный цикл, который нагенерил мне гигабайт логов за 5 минут :)

Comment: Исправил бесконечный цикл, но, почему-то, вывод каждого массива дублируется 9 раз. Я вижу 9 одинаковых блоков с данными, итого 90 блоков. А должно быть 10.

Comment: Не знаю, зачем нужен был второй foreach, но я его убрал и всё заработало нормально.

Comment: *Не знаю, зачем нужен был второй foreach* - почитайте учебники по PHP, посмотрите какая структура данных приходит в *вашем случае*, потренируйтесь на *разных* структурах, научитесь пользоваться отладчиком... Ей-богу, как дитё пятилетнее...